# Failure to get cluster config - IBM Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I have a cluster created on IBM Cloud that I can't access. When I try the following command

```
ibmcloud ks cluster-config mycluster
```

I get this response :

FAILED

```
{"incidentID":"4d426527e73acd83-CDG","code":"A0006","description":"The specified cluster could not be found. Target a region. If you're using resource groups, make sure that you target the correct resource group.","type":"Authentication","recoveryCLI":"To list the clusters you have access to, run 'ibmcloud ks clusters'. To check the resource group ID of the cluster, run 'ibmcloud ks cluster-get \u003ccluster_name_or_ID\u003e'. To list the resource groups that you have access, run 'ibmcloud resource groups'. To target the resource group, run 'ibmcloud target -g \u003cresource_group\u003e'. To target a region, run 'ibmcloud ks region-set'."}
```

I've tried to contact the IBM support team, but I still have no helpful answer to my issue. But when I try this to get the list of my clusters, it works, and I can see that my cluster actually exists.

I also tried all the commands from the JSON error message, but still it doesn't work.

```
ibmcloud ks clusters
```

From what I saw on IBM the `ibmcloud ks cluster-config mycluster` command is supposed to download the configuration file, but since it doesn't even find my cluster, I don't get anything.

Hopefully someone has had this issue before and/or can help me to figure it out, I'm running out of ideas.

**UPDATE**

I also tried

```
ibmcloud ks cluster-config --cluster mycluster
```

It returns the same JSON error message.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04

**UPDATE 2**

Even though I managed to manually get the cluster config and deploy a "hello-world" app, all commands refering to the cluster such as `ibmcloud ks workers <cluster_name_or_ID>` and `ibmcloud ks cluster-config <cluster_name_or_ID>` still don't work, and I firmly believe there is no way to fully use IBM Cloud without these commands working correctly.

Comment: `ibmcloud ks cluster-config --cluster <cluster name or ID>` is the syntax. Is that an error in your question or in your actual command?

Comment: neither, my friend. I actually tried the command you just mentionned before writing my post, and I get the exact same message. By the way, I'm going to update my post.

Comment: Your command should work as it is with just the cluster name (--cluster is not required). It looks like it cannot find your cluster, what is returned when you run the `ibmcloud ks clusters` command and are you targeting the correct region?

Comment: It returns the list of clusters I have, and I only have one. I get its name, ID, state, creation date, the right ressource group, and so forth. All the right information about my cluster. But for some reason ```ibmcloud ks cluster-config mycluster``` just doesn't work.

Comment: same issue with ubuntu 19.04 and ibmcloud 0.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but you could bypass the failing command by manually downloading and 'exporting' the kubeconfig. The download link can be found by going to your cluster in IBM Cloud, then under Access, it's part of the tutorial.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see it earlier since I went to that webpage https://cloud.ibm.com/kubernetes/clusters/8e78135c14ca4f1592e11f0be1398751/access?region=eu-gb&resourceGroup=d54a41253874468484227b46ab2679a6 several times over the last 7 days, and I'm not the only one not to have seen this as an obvious alternative to the command not working. By the way, I will still have to use that command, because it's required to display information (cush as the deployed app's IP address), and I still get the same JSON error response. But at least I can access my cluster. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, same for my colleague. He get's the same error when he tries 'ibmcloud ks workers --cluster <cluster>'. However you can also find node information by navigating to the kubernetes dashboard nodes page.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen problems using `ibmcloud ks cluster-config` with *free clusters* in the eu-gb region. If this applies to you, try using the appropriate regional endpoint to see if it helps.

For example:

```
ibmcloud ks init --host https://eu-gb.containers.cloud.ibm.com
```

See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-regions-and-zones#regions_free

Comment: Thanks Richard, I was hitting this exact problem and your command fixed it.

Comment: Thanks mate!!! Indeed, I had old free cluster in other region > removed it. 
Created a new one in eu-gb > London
After that, running the command was not possible.
Simply initializing the endpoint fixed the issue!

Answer (score 2):

The command for obtaining the cluster configuration is:

```
USAGE:
       ibmcloud ks cluster-config --cluster <cluster name or ID> [--admin] [--export] [--yaml] [--network] [--skip-rbac]
```

It seems you are omitting the **--cluster** part. I just checked and it gives the error message you are reporting.

`ibmcloud ks clusters` lists the clusters and their resource groups. Run `ibmcloud target` and check that the resource group matches the cluster's group. Else, run `ibmcloud target -g the-resource-group` to switch to it.

P.S.: Are you using the latest version of the ks plugin?

Comment: Even with the --cluster part, it returns the same error. Maybe I have forgotten something else ?

Comment: I extended my response.

Comment: I did "ibm cloud target" and it returns the right ressource group (I checked on my IBM Dashbord). And I use the version 0.3.8 if the ks plugin, which I believe to be the latest.

Comment: In that case, if everything matches, it is not a question for SO anymore, but something for IBM support.

Comment: my team leader did report the issue to the IBM Support team before I posted it here, but they last replied on tuesday, and what they said didn't help. I was hoping someone here already had that problem before.

Comment: When you browse to https://cloud.ibm.com/kubernetes/clusters , what is the state of the cluster that you're trying to get the config for? Thanks

Comment: The state is ```normal``` with a green dot next to the word, so it's supposed to be all good. Even the IBM support team told us that on their side it's woking just fine, which makes it even more strange. It's still not working on mine.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit: I no longer think unique naming is the issue

Perhaps you should remake your cluster with a unique name (not "mycluster")

If I recall correctly I received an error when my cluster name was not unique. My colleague did not get this error when he created his cluster with the name "mycluster", but he's running into the same problem as you.

Comment: actually my cluster's name is ```mycluster_test```. So you're saying the cluster's name is potentially the problem ? This is the only cluster I have, so the name is obviously unique. Unless there's a "list" of names that should not be used ?

Comment: I had the error/warning about non-unique name for my first cluster, I think it has to be unique region-wide (not per user). Not sure. My colleague who had "mycluster" will make a new one today.

Comment: That makes sense to me, because it would mean that using that name to access my cluster, I'm actually trying to access another user's cluster. However it's strange that I cannot access the cluster using my cluster's ID (which is supposed to be unique). So maybe you're right, but the solution to my issue might be somewhere else. I have no idea where though.

Comment: My colleague made a new cluster that is probably unique in name and it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Which means this is not about the cluster's name. But I'm "glad" not to be the only one to face that issue. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I lead the dev team for the above cli.  We have a new version of the CLI out and you no longer have to init to a specific region.  We now support a global view of the world and all regions.  Can you give this a try again?

Answer (score 0):

I used `cluster config` (without the dash) and it worked for me. So my entire command was
 `ibmcloud ks cluster config --cluster <cluster_name_or_ID>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I had to wipe my hard drive and reinstall the OS.  I installed the ibmcloud CLI, and cluster-config did not work.  I found that I'd evidently not installed the right package (or perhaps plugin), and that the syntax has changed as well.  I did this (I am on MacOS):

curl -sL https://ibm.biz/idt-installer | bash

ibmcloud cs cluster config --cluster <cluster-name>

and it worked.  The installation command I found here:
https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-developer-tools
but then noted it is shown on other web pages as well.

I don't know what, if any, differences there are between the old and new commands' behaviors or side-effects.